# Maneira mais segura para criptografar senhas em MySQL ? E a mais fácil?

Tags: mysql

Qual seria a maneira mais segura para criptografar senhas em MySQL ? E a mais fácil?

Estou usando um banco MYSQL, com a remoção da função `PASSWORD` gostaria de saber outra maneira para criptografar.

Comment: A aplicação já salvar criptografada!?

Comment: Não, vou criptografar na query MYSQL.

Comment: Já tentou essas alternativas: [Encryption and Compression Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As funções `MD5` e `AES` deveriam ser consideradas. A escolha entre uma das duas criptografias depende da sua necessidade.

`MD5` é uma das mais conhecidas, porém, se em algum momento você precisar revertê-la por algum motivo, não será possível.

`AES` é a minha criptografia favorita neste caso pois dispões das funções `AES_ENCRYPT` e `AES_DECRYPT`, assim podendo reverter a senha (usando a chave), caso haja necessidade.

Veja mais detalhes a respeito neste link: https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-criptografia-no-mysql/37179

Agora, respondendo realmente sua pergunta... A criptografia `AES` usa um valor pré-estabelecido de 128 bits só podendo ser revertida através da chave. Já a criptografia `MD5` usa um valor hexadecimal de 32 dígitos. Já ouvi falar que ambas já foram quebradas, então acho que estão em pé de igualdade.

E sobre facilidade de utilização, ambas são muito simples.

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (login, senha) VALUES ('usuario_1', MD5('abc123'));
INSERT INTO usuarios (login, senha) VALUES ('usuario_2', AES_ENCRYPT('abc123', 'chave'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a melhor opção seria deixar o banco apenas armazenar a informação, ou seja, já vir criptografada pela aplicação.

Um outra alternativa é usar a função `PASSWORD()` para criptografar as senhas ao salvar:

```
  insert into tabela(campo) values(password('minha senha'));
```

Aqui um exemplo funcionando: [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6fe50/1)
Referência: [MySql password hashing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-hashing.html)

**EDIT**: como apontado pelo @FabioC, a função `PASSWORD` foi descontinuada a partir da versão 8.0.11. É possível usar outras funções de criptografia como `SHA()`.

Comment: A função `PASSWORD()`  na versão 8.0.11 do MySQL Server não está mais disponível.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password

Comment: Interessante, não sabia disso, vou mencionar na resposta